# ASP.NET MVC An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Here is my source code:

```
       private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
       ......
       var UserManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        Order newOrder = new Order
        {             
            ApplicationUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
            ApplicationUser = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()),
            MakeDate = DateTime.Now
        };

        db.Orders.Add(newOrder);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

I indented to add the user information into the DB, however, it seems  HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager() also shares the same DBContext, this is why I have the below exception:

> {"An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker."}

Once I remove the code related to *UserManger*, no exception will be thrown out.

So how can I retrieve the User information from DB and then save it into the *order* table? Or the design is wrong because I already save the *userid* into the *order* table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr;** Declare your `db` inside every method instead of having a class attribute.

This error is occurring because your `private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();` is a class attribute. You've said it yourself:

> HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager() also shares the same DBContext

and that's your problem right there

I'd suggest switching to a Unit of Work pattern: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Another thing: when you want to edit an object with EF you have to `db.Orders.Attach(newOrder)`, but only the primary keys should be filled. If the object is already populated, entity framework won't recognize the changes.